Why does my Acura MDX smell like its' overheating but the temperature indicator is not showing it?
It's a 2010 Acura MDX and I just had a tune up done

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/60576/why-is-it-that-my-car-smells-like-its-overheating-but-my-temperature-gauge-says?rq=1
